# How to bypass URL redirect set in IIS 6

Tags: iis, redirect, iis-6

We are migrating from our old site to the new site. I set URL redirect in the old IIS 6 and now all traffic gets redirected to the new site. However, from time to time, I still would like to access the old site somehow. Is that anyway to bypass the site-wide redirect? Anyway to perhaps open up a "back-door" that I could still somehow visit the old site? Any best practice for this?

Comment: How have you setup the redirect?

Comment: Hi Kami, it was done through Properties>Home Directory>A redirection to a URL...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another site to IIS that points at the web folders. Just make sure that you set your server bindings with a different host header (if using a shared IP address). For example if your site is:

```
www.mydomain.com - 172.16.3.100
```

then set up the new site as:

```
www2.mydomain.com - 172.16.3.100
```

If you're using any absolute urls i.e. `http://www.mydomain.com/some_resource`, depend on the host name in anyway in your code, then life won't be quite so easy.